# rgl package has non-zero status

Tags: rgl

installing to /home/mhasanyar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgl/libs
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘hcl.colors’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rgl’

- removing ‘/home/mhasanyar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgl’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old R version, earlier than R 3.6.0 where `hcl.colors` was introduced.  The best thing you can do would be to update R, and then things should work.

If you can't do that or don't want to, then you can install `rgl` into versions as early as R 3.3.0, but you need to get the development version to do that.  It contains a number of fixes to get it working in old R versions.  The easiest way to do this is to install the `remotes` package, then run

```
remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")
```